# Getting a Jtextarea to be able to be copied over

Tags: java, jtextarea, look-and-feel

I have a question related to updating my Java version from version 6 to 7. And while there were very few changes I had to make to my program I did notice something strange. I used to be able to copy the text within the panel and paste it on a note pad if I wanted to. But with the recent Java upgrade I find that I am not able to do this any more. I made changes to the style code for it but I am not sure if there is anything I am missing and the repository does not show any change at all to it.

Here is the code, for my JTextArea:

```
public void SetStyleForTextAreaLabel( JTextArea ta) {
    ta.setEditable( false);
    ta.setHighlighter( null);
    ta.setLineWrap( true);
    ta.setWrapStyleWord( true);
    ta.setEnabled( false);
    ta.setDisabledTextColor( Color.black);
    ta.setBackground( this.getBackground());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `setEnabled(true)`.  Also, since you are setting the highlighter to null, it may be that you cannot see what is being selected.  Try this:

```
public void SetStyleForTextAreaLabel( JTextArea ta) {
    ta.setEditable( false);
    ta.setLineWrap( true);
    ta.setWrapStyleWord( true);
    ta.setDisabledTextColor( Color.black);
    ta.setBackground( this.getBackground());
}
```

Comment: @GilbertV My suggestion is to NOT remove the highlighter (i.e., do not set it to null) and also to NOT disable text area.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and i was mistaken I was able to get the highlighter to show with your suggestion. Turns out i just needed the set Highlighter alone removed.